Fourier Analysis / Power Spectrum on a Set of Batches of Numbers
I posted this question around 4 years ago Function to spot randomness and/or predict future data which was answered ok.
That operated on sequential set of numbers.
Now I like to perform the same calculation against a set of data that comes in batches of 7 for each run. Each number has a range from 1->49
full-input-file
5,10,11,21,24,43,32
7,25,28,31,36,45,49
1,3,15,19,36,37,2
6,9,17,23,26,36,42
4,7,18,21,41,46,37
19,21,27,33,36,38,3
etc...
5,11,26,31,36,39,4
11,20,33,34,37,39,22
11,17,34,37,41,49,5
16,25,29,37,45,49,20

Question is twofold:
1-How can we first group each set into a single, meaninful set of data (ex: 2-number relation, etc), then propagate into the following sets to see randomness p values. In other words build a relation between the 7 sets of numbers which occur at the same time.
Then cross-sets (across to the next rows of numbers which occur at evenly distributed set of times in the future - between each row/set time passed is T) will be a Fourier/power-series or correlation methods to gather periodicity (if exists).
2-Generate another 220 set of 7 numbers, purely randomly. perform same calculations as above, then compare the delta between the 2 sets to see varioations between the real set and a pseudo-random set.
Updates:
Ok allow me to be more specific on a method which I will need help with implementing:
I would like to define a weighing to each pairs of numbers in this fashion:
If they both occur on the same time, they get a max weight of 1. Ex: [5,10] or [5][11], etc....  If they occur at a distance of 1, that wieghing drops by a constant value, say 1%. Ex: [5][7] or [5][25] get a weight of 0.99....and similarly, [5][1] and [5][3] get a weight of 0.98 ... as there are 220 rows of data, the largets distance is 219. and in fact those weights should be distributed by ~0.46  instead of 1  [100/219].
At the end of the calculation we will have 49C2=1176 sets of duos (note a number against itself also has a max weight of 1)  Then this can be used as a power spectrum to define the possibility of the 221st set based on those weights.  I need a Mathematica simple method to calculate this.
